# DTD problem in media file

Tags: android, eclipse, dtd, assets, andengine

I'm trying to build the andengine ( http://www.andengine.org/ )examples in eclipse, but can't continue because eclipse is trying to parse a .mod file (an audio resource?) as XML.  Do I need to change the project configuration or change something in eclipse?  The exact error is:

```
Description 
The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.   

Resource    
lepeltheme.mod  

Path    
/AndEngineExamples/assets/mfx   

Location    
line 1  

Type
DTD Problem
```

I'm very new to eclipse and a beginner in Java.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

what Eclipse version are you using? What plugins do you have installed?

In case you don't care about the ModPlayerExample, simply delete the file. All other Examples should run fine.

Best Regards,
Nicolas

Comment: "Installation Details" shows something like about 50 plugins, but all I've consciously installed are the andengine examples and adk.  Eclipse version is Helios Service Release 1, 20100917-0705

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely the Eclipse editor preferences.

You need to change XML validation.

In Eclipse select Window->Preferences, then XML Files->XML Validation. Under "Validating files" switch"No grammar specificed" into IGNORE.

That should hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: Afterward you'll need properly need to clean you project, and even better delete all error in your Problem view and delete them, then recompile